# Link App Profile Page With App

Tags: facebook, profile, fan-page, vanity-url

We recently *accidently* deleted the connection between the vanity URL page and our App Profile page; by doing so, the "Go To App" button was also removed from the App Profile page.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to display the "Go To App" Button on the app Profile page (so that our users can access the App?
2. Is there a way to reconnect (re-associate) the two pages (Vanity URL Page and App Profile Page).

It seems like the only connection option we're given on the admin page is to create a new Community page and connect it to the App - (we assume that this option would not work for us since we already once migrated all the likes back in December/January when we created the Vanity URL page.

No where we can find an answer for either the re-connection nor for displaying the "Go To App" button in the App Profile page even though the category is already set to (Product > App). We appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are in a pickle.

It looks like Facebook has removed the ability for you to link an existing Page to an App - something that was added before they removed App Profile Pages. If you contact Facebook, maybe they can link the two back together some other way. As for a manual approach, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried merge page option. Create a new page for your app and then name it to be exactly like the page where you have all the likes. Now goto this page (with likes) and edit details -> resources and click on merge pages.

This should work but there is a bug in the system preventing this to happen, here are the details.

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/413029272079414?browse=search_5033475a2a50c9f73780526